# Como faço para somar valores de id vindo de um array no total

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Eu pego 2 resultados de um array, por exemplo: 1 e 9, esses números são ID's que irei usar para uma consulta no banco e imprimir esses resultados na tela, até consigo imprimir, mas por exemplo se for encontrado no bd 20 resultados com esses ID's ele imprime separado e não soma o total como esta na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu coloquei um post parecido como este mas um dos moderadores disse que não estava claro a minha dúvida, e estou há semanas tentando resolver isso e não consigo, vejam o trecho o php

```html
    <?PHP
$negocio = strip_tags( $_POST['negocio'] );
    $tipo   = strip_tags( $_POST['tipo'] );
    $cidade  = $_POST['cidade'];
    $bairro = $_POST['bairro'] ;

     echo $negocio;
     echo $tipo;
    foreach($cidade as $cidades_2){
     
     echo $cidades_2;
     
     
    }

    foreach($bairro as $bairros_2){
     

     


    $id_bairros=$bairros_2;


   


AQUI É ONDE SOMA OS VALORES VINDO DO ARRAY PARA PEGAR SOMENTE OS IDS SELECIONADOS NO SELECT
    /* MONTA CRITERIOS DE BUSCA */              
    $where = "i.ativo ='1'";
    if ( !empty( $negocio) ) {
    $where .=" AND i.id_negocio_tipo='".$negocio."'";
    if ( !empty( $tipo ) ) {
    $where .=" AND i.id_tipo_imovel='".$tipo."'";
    }
    }
    if ( !empty( $cidades_2 ) ) {
    $where .=" AND i.id_cidade='".$cidades_2."'";
    }
    if ( !empty( $id_bairro ) ) {
    $where .=" AND i.bairro='".$id_bairro."'";
    }


AQUI É SELECT PARA FAZER A PAGINAÇÃO
    ////////
    $sql = $MySQLi->query("SELECT i.*, t.tipo_nome, n.tipo, c.cidade FROM imoveis
    i LEFT JOIN negocio_tipo n ON (n.id = i.id_negocio_tipo)
    LEFT JOIN imoveis_tipo t ON (t.id = i.id_tipo_imovel)
    LEFT JOIN cidades c ON (c.id = i.id_cidade)
    WHERE ".$where."") or print(mysqli_error());
    if (!isset( $_GET["pagina"] ) )
    $pagina = 1;
    else
    $pagina = strip_tags( $_GET["pagina"] );
    $max=8;
    $inicio = $pagina - 1;
    $inicio = $max * $inicio;
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    /* calcula a quantidade de produtos sendo exibidos no momento */
    $pgs = ceil($total / $max);
    $de = $max * $pagina; 
    if($pagina == $pgs) $de = $total;
    $temp = $inicio + 1;



AQUI TERIA QUE SOMAR O TOTAL DOS IDS VINDOS DO ARRAY 1 E 9 E MOSTRAR NUM SÓ RESULTADO

    if (!empty( $total )==1 ) {
    echo "<br /><br /><div class='codigo_busca'><p><b>Resultado da Busca de Imóveis</b></p><p>Foram encontrados <b>".$total."</b> imóveis.</p>"."<br />";
    echo "<p><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:#FF0;'><b>Página:</b></span> <span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;'>".$pagina." de ".$pgs."</span></p></div><br /><br />";



AQUI É O SELECT PARA FAZER A BUSCA E IMPRIMIR O RESULTADO NA TELA
    //////////
    $sql =$MySQLi->query("SELECT i.id, i.valor, i.foto_exibicao, i.quartos, i.garagem, i.codigo, t.tipo_nome, n.tipo AS negocio, c.cidade, c.uf, b.bairro FROM imoveis i
    LEFT JOIN negocio_tipo n ON (n.id = i.id_negocio_tipo)
    LEFT JOIN imoveis_tipo t ON (t.id = i.id_tipo_imovel)
    LEFT JOIN cidades c ON (c.id = i.id_cidade)
    LEFT JOIN bairros b ON (b.id = i.bairro)
    WHERE ".$where." ORDER BY valor ASC LIMIT ".$inicio.", ".$max."") or print(mysqli_error());
    while( $linha = mysqli_fetch_array( $sql ) ) {
    $foto=$linha['foto_exibicao'];
    $tipos=$linha['tipo_nome']; 
    $tipo = $tipos;
    $tipo  = strtolower( str_replace(" ", "-", strtr(utf8_decode(trim($tipo)), utf8_decode("áàãâéêíóôõúüñçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÑÇ"),"aaaaeeiooouuncAAAAEEIOOOUUNC-")) );
    $bairros=$linha['bairro']; 
    $bairro = $bairros;
    $bairro = strtolower( str_replace(" ", "-", strtr(utf8_decode(trim($bairro)), utf8_decode("áàãâéêíóôõúüñçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÑÇ"),"aaaaeeiooouuncAAAAEEIOOOUUNC-")) );
    $cidades=$linha['cidade']; 
    $cidade = $cidades;
    $cidade = strtolower( str_replace(" ", "-", strtr(utf8_decode(trim($cidade)), utf8_decode("áàãâéêíóôõúüñçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÑÇ"),"aaaaeeiooouuncAAAAEEIOOOUUNC-")) );
    ?>
```

Então pessoal o código esta todo comentando para melhor compreensão, e desculpem pelo texto grande, e se alguém puder me ajudar ficaria grato ..

Comment: Você quer mostrar a quantidade de resultados retornados do banco de dados ?

Answer (score 0):

Está meio complicado entender. Mas pelo que entendi você quer somar $temp + $total.

```
echo ($temp+$total);
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder, eu consigo pegar os valores buscados mas em vez de mostrar tudo num só resultado mostra separado, apesar de eu estar ciente que isso acontece porque esta dentro do loop do foreach mas se eu tirar fora do loop ele só pega o último id vindo do array. É só olha na imagem que postei o primeira busca é do id 1 e a segunda busca é do id 9 mas queria esses resultado numa só busca , entendeu, em vez de mostrar assim mostrasse na imagem 8 imóveis buscados.